# Почему нет метки SSIS?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, создание-метки

Почему нет метки SSIS? Она включена в sql-server?

Comment: Хорошо, что не `ISIS`

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Напишите в вопросе - что такое SSIS и как она связана с SQL-Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда нет метки, её можно создать, просто поставив на вопрос. Для этого надо иметь [всего 300 баллов репутации](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: Вы пытаетесь создать метку [ssis], хотя уже существует метка [ssi]! Если вы всё равно считаете, что новая метка необходима, заведите обсуждение на Мете

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, вот с этого и надо было начинать. Это английская автопроверка на множественное число. На какой вопрос поставить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851236/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-ssis-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, создал. Добавь ей описание. И поставь ещё куда-нибудь, а то если вопрос только один, то она удалится через полгода.

Comment: [tag:integration-services] еще есть

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, это одно и то же или нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да. Из 14 вопросов 12 про SQL Server Intgration Services. Можно объединить с новой меткой и перенести описание.