# Как предложить более частый синоним?

Tags: поддержка, синонимы-меток, инструменты-модератора

Движок не даёт предложить синоним, даже несмотря на то, что я модератор:

> [image: скриншот]

> Не удалось предложить синоним:
>
> Не удаётся создать синоним; метка [матрица] встречается более чем в 1.25 раз чаще метки [матрицы]

Comment: Поменять метку в вопросах, чтоб вопросов с [tag:матрицы] стало больше)

Comment: @Suvitruf, уже разобрался.

Comment: @Suvitruf, запостил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

1. Предложить синоним как получается, т. е. наоборот.
2. Пойти на страницу утверждения синонимов и нажать кнопку <kbd>переставить</kbd>.
3. Утвердить синоним.
4. Дальше слияние по обычной схеме.

Comment: Получается смысла этой валидации нет, если её всё равно приходится так обходить, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а разве тебе доступна кнопка "переставить" в синонимах? Подозреваю, что обойти могут только модераторы?

Comment: Нет, но попросить модератов сделать X — тоже обходной путь. Вообще эту синонимизацию сделали очень сложной в плане разрешения самим сообществом и получается, что весь подобный груз ложиться на плечи модераторов и написания кучи специфических постов на мете простыми участниками.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, наверное решили, что без модераторов предлагать более частую метку в качестве синонима более редкой - так себе затея. Тем более, множественное число для английского языка решается [проверкой на букву `s`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7508/178988),  которую тоже только модераторы могут обойти.